# Wordpress ReCapcha

Tags: php, wordpress, recaptcha

I am currently trying to finish migrating a Wordpress site and have ran into an issue. The recapcha is not set on our temp domain and we currently cannot set it.

Is it possible to disable the invisible recapcha without going into the admin panel? I can't find anything in the database nor in the files.

Comment: If you are using google recaptcha you can be able to add the temp domain under that recaptcha

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply but as I said I can't set it currently as the client is away. Do you have any idea where we can disable it without being in the admin panel?

Comment: No you need admin access

Answer (score 0):

So if you have use your theme that has template folder, you might get a file called form-template, inside your theme folder. Within the file, there are sets of Input tag that you can delete. But, it depends on what theme and plugin are you using in your WP. Because different theme and plugin has different way to retrieve the input tag template.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However it's just a theme and the issue is the login page not the theme. I'm trying to disable the hidden capcha..